# How to get in axios with filter and limit value

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to know how can I implement or is there a better way to call a get function with filter and limit value on it?

In my swagger, I input this values

[image]

So far here is my working code:

```
    const loadData = async () => {
    const result = await api.get(
      "guidelines?filter=type_name%7C%7C%24eq%7C%7CTerms%20%26%20Conditions&limit=1"
    );
    setData(result.data[0]);
  };
```

How can I make filter more dynamic and is capable of handling multiple filters?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to get more elements instead of the first element in result.data?

Comment: Hi Sir @Greg, I want to update my get function to more not hardcoded way